# Why does creating a 2x8 R8 texture from a 16 byte buffer fail in webgl2?

Tags: webgl2

When I try to create a 2x8 R8 texture in webgl2, I get an error. This doesn't happen for a 4x8 texture. If I double the size of the input buffer compared to what I expect, the 2x8 succeeds.

Does webgl2 have a 'column alignment' of 4 when creating/reading textures?

Here is some code that reproduces the issue. I tested it on Windows in both Chrome and Firefox:

```js
function test_read(w) {
    let gl = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('webgl2');
    let h = 8;
    let data = new Uint8Array(w*h);
    data[5] = 5;

    let texture = gl.createTexture();
    let frameBuffer = gl.createFramebuffer();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.R8, w, h, 0, gl.RED, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
    if (gl.getError() !== gl.NO_ERROR) {
        return 'bad w=' + w;
    }
    return 'good w=' + w;
}

console.log(test_read(4)); // good w=4
console.log(test_read(2)); // bad w=2
```

The error code coming out is 0x502 (INVALID_OPERATION). A similar issue happens when reading textures that were created by expanding the buffer: it seems to expect a 'column alignment' of 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1)`

The default `UNPACK_ALIGNMENT` is 4 which means WebGL expects every row of pixel to be a multiple of 4 bytes. Since you're using R8 (1 byte pixel) and a width of 2 your rows are only 2 bytes long. When you change the width to 4 it starts working.

```js
function test_read(w) {
    let gl = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('webgl2');
    let h = 8;
    let data = new Uint8Array(w*h);
    data[5] = 5;

    // ---=== ADDED ===---
    gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

    let texture = gl.createTexture();
    let frameBuffer = gl.createFramebuffer();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.R8, w, h, 0, gl.RED, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
    if (gl.getError() !== gl.NO_ERROR) {
        return 'bad w=' + w;
    }
    return 'good w=' + w;
}

console.log(test_read(4)); // good w=4
console.log(test_read(2)); // bad w=2
```